# How to pass first N args to a C++ function

Tags: c++11, lambda, c++14, variadic-functions, generic-lambda

I've got a function like this:

```
void loadData(std::function<void (std::string, std::string, std::string)> callback)
{
    // data loading stuff
    callback(body, subject, header);
}
```

The problem is I'm not necessarily need to use `subject` and `header` in my callback function. Now I'm handling it this way:

```
loadData([](std::string body, std::string, std::string){
    std::cout << body;
})
```

I want to replace it with

```
loadData([](std::string body){
    std::cout << body;
})
```

and automatically pass to callback function as many arguments as it able to accept.
I don't want to manually overload `loadData` function for all 3 possible argument counts. I also don't want to use any more complicated lambda syntax on the calling site because my library should be clear for others to use.
Is this possible using C++ STL and Boost?

Comment: Why not just overload? or just ignore the other two parameters

Comment: @Mgetz because I beleive I can face this issue once again when I'll have more than 3 args, and the more overloads I have here, the uglier and less readable my code becomes.

Comment: I assume there's some reason you don't want to put the arguments in a `struct` to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got inspired by one of the other answers, which proposes to make a wrapper that passes the correct number of parameters to the functor. I find this solution very nice, and thought I would try make a general templated wrapper, where the number of arguments is not hardcoded. Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct WrapperHelp
{
   template
      <  typename L
      ,  typename Tuple
      ,  std::size_t... Is
      ,  typename... Ts
      >
   static auto apply(L&& l, Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... ts)
      -> decltype(l(std::get<Is>(t)...))
   {
      return l(std::get<Is>(t)...);
   }

   template
      <  typename L
      ,  typename Tuple
      ,  std::size_t... Is
      ,  typename T1
      ,  typename... Ts
      >
   static auto apply(L&& l, Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>, T1&& t1, Ts&&... ts)
      -> decltype(WrapperHelp::apply(std::forward<L>(l), std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(t)..., t1), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) +1 >(), ts...))
   {
      return WrapperHelp::apply(std::forward<L>(l), std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(t)..., t1), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) + 1>(), ts...);
   }
};

template<typename L>
struct OptionalWrapper {
   public:
      OptionalWrapper(L l) : lambda{std::move(l)} {}

      template<typename... Ts>
      void operator()(Ts&&... ts) const
      {
         WrapperHelp::apply(lambda, std::tuple<>(), std::index_sequence<>(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
      }

   private:
      L lambda;
};

template<typename L>
auto makeOptionalWrapper(L l) { return OptionalWrapper<L>{std::move(l)}; }

template<class F>
void loadData(OptionalWrapper<F>&& callback)
{
   std::string body = "body";
   std::string subject = "subject";
   std::string header = "header";
   double lol  = 2.0;
   callback(body, subject, header, lol);
}

template<typename L>
void loadData(L callback)
{
    loadData(makeOptionalWrapper(std::move(callback)));
}

int main() {
   //apply(std::tuple<double>(2), std::tuple<double>(2));
   loadData([](auto&& body) { 
      std::cout << body << std::endl;
   });
   loadData([](auto&& body, auto&& subject) { 
      std::cout << body << " " << subject << std::endl;
   });
   loadData([](auto&& body, auto&& subject, auto&& header) { 
      std::cout << body << " " << subject << " " << header << std::endl;
   });
   loadData([](auto&& body, auto&& subject, auto&& header, auto&& lol) { 
      std::cout << body << " " << subject << " " << header << " " << lol << std::endl;
   });
   return 0;
}
```

This should work for any function, with any number of "optional" parameters, and with any types of parameters. It is not the prettiest code, but I hope the idea is clear and can be of some use :)

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eaa97a295df64f5)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've looked for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DenisSheremet No problem, glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 6):

What about ignoring the following arguments using `...` ?

```
loadData([](std::string body, ...){
    std::cout << body;
})
```

---

As pointed by StoryTeller (thanks!) the use of ellipsis can be unsupported for non trivial types (see [[expr.call]p9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#9) for more details).

To avoid this problem, if you can use C++14, you can use `auto ...` (better `auto && ...` to avoid unnecessary copies; thanks Yakk).

```
loadData([](std::string body, auto && ...){
    std::cout << body;
})
```

Comment: Passing anything but the most trivial types is only conditionally supported.

Comment: @StoryTeller - not sure to understand; do you mean that `...` is guaranteed to support only trivial types?

Comment: I think it would be better to use unnamed tempate parameter pack instead.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot - do you mean `auto ...`? Was my first idea but, unfortunately, it's available only from C++14 and the OP tagged this question as C++11.

Comment: The tags is meant to be "C++11 and newer", so i've added C++14 as well. Your solution is good, but I'll wait a bit for a better approaches before accepting it.

Comment: Can be unsupported means what exactly? Is it mostly safe to use until you run into problems?

Comment: @kim366 - sorry but I'm not a standard expert and the page pointed by StoryTeller is (for me, at least) a little obscure; anyway I read words as "Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type having a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics" so I suppose the compiler, in these circumstances, can do what it wants.

Comment: @DenisSheremet - well... if C++14 is well for you, forget the C-style version.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a wrapper around the lambda.

```
template<typename L>
struct OptionalWrapper {
    OptionalWrapper(L l) : lambda{std::move(l)} {}

    void operator()(std::string body, std::string subject, std::string header) const {
        call(lambda, body, subject, header);
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    auto call(T& l, std::string body, std::string subject, std::string header) const
        -> decltype(l(body, subject, header))
    {
        return l(body, subject, header);
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto call(T& l, std::string body, std::string subject, std::string) const
        -> decltype(l(body, subject))
    {
        return l(body, subject);
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto call(T& l, std::string body, std::string, std::string) const
        -> decltype(l(body))
    {
        return l(body);
    }

    L lambda;
};

template<typename L>
auto makeOptionalWrapper(L l) { return OptionalWrapper<L>{std::move(l)}; }
```

Then, use your wrapper like that:

```
void loadData(std::function<void (std::string, std::string, std::string)> callback)
{
    callback(body, subject, header);
}

template<typename L>
void loadData(L callback)
{
    loadData({makeOptionalWrapper(std::move(callback))});
}
```